# User Created Slideshow

Tags: 7, views, media

I am new to Drupal and I'm looking for a slideshow of user uploaded images on a user uploaded project. Basically, I want the user uploaded images to be shown on the content page, in addition to text, ratings, comments, etc. I downloaded Views Slideshow and dependencies, then added a field on the content type the images go on, so users can add any number (actually it's capped at 10, but that shouldn't really matter) of images.

After that, I found myself stuck. Every single result on Google was somewhere along the lines of "Create a View and Use it" without enough detail on either.

How do I get a user created slideshow of images on content the user made?

Comment: Do you want to display the slideshow in Node View page or any in view's page?

Comment: I don't know, I am REALLY new to this. I just want it to show on the content page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [field_slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) module and enable it. After enabling go-to this [link](http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle.all.js) and download as `jquery.cycle.all.js`, place it under `sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle`. Clear cache after this.

After enabling go-to `manage display` and in your image format select as `Slideshow`.

Attaching screenshots.

[image]

[image]